# Monitoring Innodb Lock Monitoring output?

Tags: mysql, monitoring, logging, locking

I've found plenty of tools that will monitor the output of SHOW PROCESSLIST and SHOW INNODB STATUS but haven't really found much that indicates it will log, digest and summarize (optionally enabled) data from the InnoDB Lock Monitor.  Is there such a tool?

(FWIW, I know I can enable the slow_query_log and have done that, but want to be able to log more specific locking activities over time. What is difficult to tell when encountering a slow query is what other thread/query/user caused it without manual inspection.)

Answer (score 1):

[`innotop`](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/09/18/how-to-debug-innodb-lock-waits/) can be used to display locks in a prettier format than the raw data, but it's more of a point in time view. If you're looking for something like long-term statistics and summaries, I'm not aware of anything.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of innotop, but nothing for long-term like you.